# How to debug "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Debug: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jwt, amazon-cognito, bearer-token, .net-8.0

I am going through the extremely painful process of updating a .NET core 1.1 MVC web service which has been in production, untouched, for 9 years.  I'm attempting to convert to .NET 8.0.  I'm trying to get the service to validate AWS Cognito bearer tokens.  I have the issuer configured properly (I verify the string exactly matches the iss field in the decoded JWT) but I simply see this in the debug output:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Debug: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.

I have default logging level set to trace as well as calling out trace for individual components:

{
"Logging": {
"IncludeScopes": false,
"LogLevel": {
"Default": "Trace",
"System": "Trace",
"Microsoft": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Trace",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Trace"
}
}
}

and I have set various JwtBearer options that would appear to increase information:

```
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0),
                RequireAudience = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "proper aws url",
                **LogValidationExceptions = true,
                LogTokenId = true,**
            };
            options.UseSecurityTokenValidators = true;
            **options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;**
```

Yet the tracing produced seems extremely limited (one line) and unspecific.  This seems crazy, I must be missing something.  How can I debug this to figure out where the validation is going wrong?  Is there some way to insert my own passthrough class into this chain so I can at least see which function is failing, what it is taking for params, etc?

Comment: Can you share your full authentication  setup ? these are just token validation parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .net8 setting up authentication you need to add authentication scheme and `JWT Bearer` :

```
          var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
          builder.Services
                .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                {
                    var configManager = new 
                    ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                    settings.DiscoveryUrl,
                    new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
    
                    opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                    opt.SaveToken = true;
                    opt.ConfigurationManager = configManager;
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3),
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = settings.Issuer,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidAudiences = settings.Audience,
                        NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Upn
                    };
                });
         services.AddAuthorizationCore(opt =>
         {
           //Your policies here
         });

    // Other configuration
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  It ended up being a CORS issue that was preventing the authorization header from arriving in the OPTIONS http request.  I disabled "Just My Code" and was able to step through the .NET auth code to see that it wasn't seeing an auth header at all.  Oddly, there is no log statement in the .NET code to note this rather significant circumstance, it just results with the unhelpful "Bearer was not authenticated".  But once I was able to step through the code and find that detail I could track the cause.  Would have been tough if I didn't have the ability to use a debugger.